# Compiling ImageMagick with Emscripten - Unresolved Symbols

Tags: imagemagick, emscripten

I compiled ImageMagick with Emscripten with the following parameters

```
emconfigure ./configure --prefix=/home/roman/Desktop/src/ImageMagick/out --enable-delegate-build

emmake make
```

ImageMagick compiled without issues.
Now I'm trying to use the built libraries `libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.a` and `libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.a` in a basic app.

When I compile my app I get following warnings

```
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZNKSt3__212basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4copyEPcmm
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6appendEPKcm
warning: unresolved symbol: _Znwm
```

Seems to be missing stl symbols that are required by ImageMagic. When I use llvm-nm on the ImageMagic libraries that I've build, I see that these symbols are not defined ('U' next to the symbol).

How could I fix that?

Comment: Those methods are from `libc++`.  Might need to revise the LD_FLAGS, and review the EM docs about C++ applications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...the problem was that I've compiled ImageMagick with a different version of emscripten than the app. I didn't realize that `git pull + emsdk install` won't actually install the newest version. But once I've seen directory names in emsdk (1.38.8 vs 1.38.10) , I realized that I used 2 different versions and just deleted and reinstalled new version. Specifying LDFLAGS was useful for pointing to jpeg libs when building with `--enable-delegate-build`.